# mat-contenteditable stopped working after upgrading angular, angular mat to version 13

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, package.json, angular13

mat-contenteditable cuases errors after upgrading anguarl version from 12 to 13

```
Error: /node_modules/mat-contenteditable/lib/mat-ckeditor.directive.d.ts:9:22 - error TS2420: Class 'MatCkeditorDirective' incorrectly implements interface 'CanUpdateErrorState'.
  Property 'updateErrorState' is missing in type 'MatCkeditorDirective' but required in type 'CanUpdateErrorState'.

9 export declare class MatCkeditorDirective extends _MatInputMixinBase implements MatFormFieldControl<string>, DoCheck, CanUpdateErrorState, OnInit {
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  /node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/error-state.d.ts:17:5
    17     updateErrorState(): void;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'updateErrorState' is declared here.


Error: /node_modules/mat-contenteditable/lib/mat-contenteditable.directive.d.ts:4:29 - error TS2305: Module '"@angular/material/core"' has no exported member 'CanUpdateErrorStateCtor'.

4 import { ErrorStateMatcher, CanUpdateErrorStateCtor, CanUpdateErrorState } from '@angular/material/core';
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error:/node_modules/mat-contenteditable/lib/mat-contenteditable.directive.d.ts:19:22 - error TS2420: Class 'MatContenteditableDirective' incorrectly implements interface 'CanUpdateErrorState'.
  Property 'updateErrorState' is missing in type 'MatContenteditableDirective' but required in type 'CanUpdateErrorState'.

19 export declare class MatContenteditableDirective extends _MatInputMixinBase implements ControlValueAccessor, MatFormFieldControl<string>, DoCheck, CanUpdateErrorState {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  /node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/error-state.d.ts:17:5
    17     updateErrorState(): void;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'updateErrorState' is declared here.




× Failed to compile.
```

package.json:

> "@angular/material": "^13.3.2",
> "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.2",
> "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^31.1.0",
> "mat-contenteditable": "^9.1.0",

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's a good way to solve the issue, i don't like to touch code that i don't own...,  but i manage to build again doing this two updates :

---

In file ***node_modules\mat-contenteditable\mat-contenteditable.directive.d.ts*** :

```
- remove --> import { CanUpdateErrorStateCtor } from '@angular/material/core';
+ add --> import { _Constructor, _AbstractConstructor } from '@angular/material/core';
+ add (just after the imports) --> declare type CanUpdateErrorStateCtor = _Constructor<CanUpdateErrorState> & _AbstractConstructor<CanUpdateErrorState>;
+ add (in the directive) --> updateErrorState(): void;
```

---

In file ***node_modules\mat-contenteditable\mat-ckeditor.directive.d.ts*** :

```
+ add (in the directive) --> updateErrorState(): void;
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing a file in /node_modules isn't definitely the best approach.

That class **CanUpdateErrorStateCtor** [has been removed in Material for Angular 13](https://dsebastien.net/blog/2021-11-05-angular-13-in-depth), so the only "safe" option is to deal with it and update the dependencies that cause that error.

I had a problem on the same class, but caused by another library (*@angular-material-components/file-input*):

```
Error: node_modules/@angular-material-components/file-input/lib/file-input.component.d.ts:4:64 - error TS2305: Module '"@angular/material/core"' has no exported member 'CanUpdateErrorStateCtor'.

4 import { CanUpdateErrorState, ErrorStateMatcher, ThemePalette, CanUpdateErrorStateCtor } from '@angular/material/core';
                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular-material-components/file-input/lib/file-input.component.d.ts:24:22 - error TS2420: Class 'NgxMatFileInputComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'CanUpdateErrorState'.
Property 'updateErrorState' is missing in type 'NgxMatFileInputComponent' but required in type 'CanUpdateErrorState'.

24 export declare class NgxMatFileInputComponent extends _NgxMatInputMixinBase implements MatFormFieldControl<FileOrArrayFile>, OnDestroy, DoCheck, CanUpdateErrorState, ControlValueAccessor {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/error-state.d.ts:17:5
17     updateErrorState(): void;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'updateErrorState' is declared here.
```

that was at version `6.0.0`, instead it needed at least version `7.0.0`. Updating that version solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At least for me, the error was caused by the library  *@angular-material-components/file-input*. I've searched by this in Google, and found that the the library was in the wrong version (4.0.0). In my case, for Angular 14, it needed 8.0.0 or greater:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/file-input

```
| Angular | @angular-material-components/file-input |
|:-------:|:---------------------------------------:|
| 15      | 9.x+                                    |
| 14      | 8.x+                                    |
| 13      | 7.x+                                    |
| 12      | 6.x+                                    |
| 11      | 5.x+                                    |
| 10      | 4.x+                                    |
| 9       | 2.x+                                    |
| 8       | 2.x+                                    |
| 7       | 2.x+                                    |
```

You can apply some similar approach in your case.